# my model field is not accepting "+" symbol into data. Using CharField field for model

Tags: django, django-models

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=14,null=True)
    add = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
    image = models.FileField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

when i give
mobile = +12345

its showing in admin as mobile = 12345

after i edit and save its showing +12345

why? and which field to use for including + symbol

Answer (score 0):

> when i give `mobile = +12345`.

You pass an `int`, Django will convert this to a `str`, but the number has as value `12345`, not `+12345`.

What you need to do is store it as a string, so:

```
Profile.objects.create(
    user=…,
    mobile='+12345',
    add=…,
    image=…
)
```

Comment: i am trying to store it as a string but + is automtically ignored when i check data or retrieve the data.

Comment: @Naveen: do you use a Django form to retrieve the data from the user?